# SQL - Select record count from column value in separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm totally stumped here, I hope I haven't overlooked an answer elsewhere.

I have two tables, `asset` and `purchase_order`.

**asset**

```
asset_key | description | purchase_order_key
```

**purchase_order**

```
purchase_order_key | order_number | number_of_assets
```

I'm trying to get a list of purchase orders, each meeting the following criteria:

- The total number of rows in the asset table with the given purchase_order_key is less than the number_of_assets value in the purchase_order row with that purchase_order_key.

For example, say the `asset` table has 4 rows with the same `purchase_order_key` (24), and 17 items with a different `purchase_order_key` (66). If `purchase_order` 24 lists 4 `number_of_assets`, and `purchase_order` 66 lists 19 `number_of_assets`, then the query should return `purchase_order` 66, but not `purchase_order` 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM purchase_order
WHERE number_of_assets > (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM asset
    WHERE asset.purchase_order_key = purchase_order.purchase_order_key
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a `COUNT` on the `assets` joined to the PO table, and then compare them with the recorded number of assets.

```
SELECT PO.purchase_order_key, COUNT(A.purchase_order_key)
FROM purchase_order PO
    LEFT JOIN asset A ON PO.purchase_order_key = A.purchase_order_key
GROUP BY PO.purchase_order_key, PO.number_of_assets
HAVING COUNT(*) > PO.number_of_assets
```

Comment: You might need a left join in case there are no `asset` rows.  Then you need to handle null values, would `count(all asset.purchase_order_key)` do it?  [(*link*)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

Comment: I don't know if this is a TSQL specific issue, but this query gives me the error: "Column 'purchase_order.number_of_assets' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: it's not TSQL specific, you'll need to add `purchase_order.number_of_assets` to the `GROUP BY` clause then. See edit

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    PO.*
FROM
    purchase_order PO
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT 
                A.purchase_order_key,
                COUNT(A.asset_key) asset_key_count
            FROM
                asset A
            GROUP BY
                A.purchase_order_key

        ) AC on AC.purchase_order_key = PO.purchase_order_key and AC.asset_key_count < PO.number_of_assets
```

Comment: Close; Jason Goemaat's code did the trick. This bit gave me all the records except for those where the number of asset records was 0.